# How do you make "enter" an invalid option in batch script?

Tags: windows, batch

I want "enter" to be invalid and to restate the acceptable responses.

```
echo.                     Do you want to root your Nexus 5?
echo.                 -----------------------------------------
echo.
echo.
echo. Y. Red  Pill......
echo. ----------------------------------------
echo.
echo      or
echo.
echo. N. Blue Pill......
echo. ----------------------------------------
echo.
set /p root="  Red Pill or Blue Pill?:  "

    if %root%==Y (root\run.bat)
    if %root%==N (exit)
    if %root%==y (root\run.bat)
    if %root%==n (exit)
```

This is Windows, 32 bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Labels and Gotos to create sub-routines.

Try something like this:

```
echo.                     Do you want to root your Nexus 5?
echo.                 -----------------------------------------
echo.
echo.
echo. Y. Red  Pill......
echo. ----------------------------------------
echo.
echo      or
echo.
echo. N. Blue Pill......
echo. ----------------------------------------
echo.
:prompt
set /p root="  Red Pill or Blue Pill?:  "

if "%root%"=="Y" goto runBat
if "%root%"=="N" goto exit
if "%root%"=="y" goto runBat
if "%root%"=="n" goto exit
if "%root%"=="" goto prompt

:runBat    
root\run.bat
goto exit

:exit
```

If you want to make anything other than Y or N (and y or n) invalid (instead of just Enter), then just remove the `if "%root%"==""` part, leaving only `goto prompt` on that line.

Comment: Rather than checking both `Y` and `y`, you can just use the case-insensitive form: `if /i "%whatever%" == "y"`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how one does such a menu in a script with [JP Software's TCC/LE](http://jpsoft.com/tccledes.htm):

```
@echo off
:: pill.btm
text
                     Do you want to root your Nexus 5?
                 -----------------------------------------


 Y. Red  Pill......
 ----------------------------------------

     or

 N. Blue Pill......
 ----------------------------------------
endtext
inkey /k"YNRB" `  `Red Pill or Blue Pill?:`  ` %%root
switch "%root%"
case "Y" .OR. "R"
    call root\run
case "N" .OR. "B"
    exit
endswitch
```

The `/k` option to `inkey` restricts what key presses are even acceptable, eliminating the need for looping back and printing extra prompts if an invalid selection is given.  The `switch` command does a case-insensitive comparison, and also supports `.OR.`.

Of course, TCC (and its predecessors) have always made it easy to present far better user interfaces from command scripts.  Here's an improved version of the aforementioned:

```
@echo off
:: pill.btm
cls white on blue
drawbox 1 10 6 70 2 green on black fill zoom shadow
drawhline 3 12 57 1 green on black
scrput 2 24 white on black Do you want to root your Nexus 5?
scrput 4 34 red on black Y. Red  Pill
scrput 5 34 blue on black N. Blue Pill
drawbox 10 39 12 41 2 green on black fill shadow
screen 11 40
inkey /k"YNRB" %%root
switch "%root%"
case "Y" .OR. "R"
    cls white on black
    scrput 4 34 red on black Y. Red  Pill
    screen 11 0
    call root\run
case "N" .OR. "B"
    cls white on black
    scrput 5 34 blue on black N. Blue Pill
    screen 11 0
    exit
endswitch
```

It's just 1 line longer, but has quite a few improvements, not the least of which is the display of the chosen "pill", in colour.

However, there's no reason that a command script in Windows has to have a Textual User Interface.  TCC can also do a graphical version, which is just a 3 liner:

```
@echo off
msgbox /2 /q continueabort "Red pill, blue pill" About to root your Nexus 5
if %_? == 15 call root\run
```

Note the use of `call`, by the way.  This is a bug in `techie007`'s script.  ☺

And it has been over 25 years.  We don't have to use `command`'s `.bat` extension.  Microsoft's `cmd` has used `.cmd` since OS/2 version 1.  You'll notice that I used TCC/LE's `.btm` above — a habit accrued from writing `.btm` scripts that would work with 4NT, 4DOS, and 4OS2.

### Further reading

- JP Software. [*INKEY*](http://jpsoft.com/help/inkey.htm).  Take Command / TCC Help.
- JP Software. [*MSGBOX*](http://jpsoft.com/help/msgbox.htm).  Take Command / TCC Help.
- JP Software. [*SWITCH*](http://jpsoft.com/help/switch.htm).  Take Command / TCC Help.
- JP Software. [*CALL*](http://jpsoft.com/help/call.htm).  Take Command / TCC Help.
- JP Software. [*.BAT, .CMD and .BTM Files*](http://jpsoft.com/help/batchtype.htm).  Take Command / TCC Help.